# Obtaining identical R2 when fitting different degrees

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

In the code below, I obtain the same `R2` parameter independently of which polynomial degree `k` I am using to fit the data. Why is that?

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Variables
rd.seed(1234)
n = 100
noise = rd.normal(0,0.1,n)

## Mock data
x = np.linspace(0,3,n)
y = x**2 + noise

## Fit

k = 2
p, cov = np.polyfit(x, y, k, cov=True)  ##

xfit = np.sort(x)
yfit = np.sort(np.polyval(p, xfit))

perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(cov)) # standard-deviation estimates for each     coefficient
R2 = np.corrcoef(x, y)[0, 1]**2  # coefficient of determination between x and y

resid = y - yfit
n = y.size ; m = p.size
dof = n - m  # degrees of freedom

chi2 = np.sum((resid/yfit)**2) # chi-squared; estimates error in data
chi2red = chi2/(dof) # reduced chi-squared; measures goodness of fit
s_err = np.sqrt(np.sum(resid**2)/(dof)) # standard deviation of the error

print('degree =', k, '\nR2 =', R2, '\nchi2 =', chi2red, '\nserr =',     s_err, '\ncoeffs a-c =', p)  

## Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,10))
plt.scatter(x, y, s=40, facecolors='', edgecolors='grey')
plt.plot(xfit, yfit, 'r--')
plt.show()
```

These two have the same `R2`:

[image]
[image]

Comment: The calculation of R2 in your code, "np.corrcoef(x, y)[0, 1]**2", is the same regardless of k, as x and y do not change with k. Incidentally, you are wise to seed the random number generator for repeatable test conditions.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like `np.corrcoef` is not valid for degrees higher than one. Among the many questions devoted to this issue, still is not clear to me what built-in function (in this case of `numpy`) is the simplest one to obtain the coefficient R2 for any k-degree fit.

Comment: R-squared is exact for straight lines, and both approximate and useful for curved lines. Use "R2 = np.corrcoef(y, yfit)[0, 1]**2" to find the relationship information on actual (y) and predicted (yfit) values.

Comment: Perfect! That was easy to implement, thanks James.